# Getting image id from SQL dataBase and setting it in imageView( Android)

Tags: sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to get image id from sql database and put it in imageView through RecyclerViewAdapter . Unfortunately I have got no luck until now.
-once I tried to put the ids in an array and getting number of array from database and calling the related array, but app force closed.
-another time I tried to get the id from database but again it didn't work and app force closed.
Who knows what is the correct way?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself.I just stored images' drawable ID in an array and the corresponding number of array element in the database.then I read the database and so called the images' array.